# Having a model in my entity framework CF with data type less memory consumption than int and string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use Entity Framework Code First.

Here I have a model:

```
public class Stop
{
    [Key]
    public int StopID { get; set; }
    public string StopCode { get; set; }
    public string StopText { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

1. Is it possible to have keys not int but less memory consumption? bytes? int16?
2. Is it possible to have string less memory consumption? string[20] ?

The problem I have is that I use a WCF service to transfer data and I exceed reasonable size.

Thanks

---

UPDATE

Here is a screenshot of typical data transfered:

[image]

One thing for sure: I have 2116 items transferred similar to the above on the screenshot. Let's try to compute the size of data transfered. I have less than 20 chars on each items. I have 2116 items so 20 * 2116 = 42320 >> far less than 600000 configured in my web.config (maxBufferPoolSize)!

Here is my config:

```
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IRequestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="600000" maxReceivedMessageSize="600000" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Having a different data type won't help you.

The data is serialised as text when transferred, so the string `"42"` that is an integer in your class would be exactly as long as the string `"42"` that is a byte in your classs. It's only the actual value in the variable that is send, so the fact that a string can contain as much as 2 GB doesn't mean that 2 GB is sent each time you send a string.

So, you should look at what's exactly making your data so large. Do you for example transfer a lot more of your objects than you think?

Comment: You must certainly be right. Something is strange in data transfered because I cannot understand why 600000 (maxBufferPoolSize in Web.Config) is not enough!? I updated my question to show you more info + screenshot. Thanks.